# Benchmark problems for computing rational points on varieties

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, computer-algebra, rational-points

Are there standard benchmark problem sets used for empirically evaluating algorithms designed for computing rational points on (various classes of) algebraic varieties?

If so, could you please point me to them?